# VBA Stock info retrieval into Excel

Tags: vba, excel, yahoo-finance, stockquotes

first off, I have to admit I'm not very good at VBA. I've tried to adapt the code from [this](http://investexcel.net/multiple-stock-quote-downloader-for-excel) and [this](http://www.marketindex.com.au/yahoo-finance-api) site to download the information I need on a list of given stock tickers. I have a list of the tickers in column A of sheet "data" and want the downloaded infos (name, exchange, bid, ask, etc.) in the columns to the right, starting in column c. I want to run the macro (and thus update all values) with a click on a button.
I tried to adapt the code accordingly but keep on running into errors I cannot debug. Can you experts help me get the code right?

Thanks so much in advance!

Error

---

```
Sub DownloadStockQuotes(ByVal stockTicker As String, ByVal DestinationCell As String)

    Dim qurl As String
    Dim StartMonth, StartDay, StartYear, EndMonth, EndDay, EndYear As String
    Dim C As WorkbookConnection
    StartMonth = Format(Month(StartDate) - 1, "00")
    StartDay = Format(Day(StartDate), "00")
    StartYear = Format(Year(StartDate), "00")

    EndMonth = Format(Month(EndDate) - 1, "00")
    EndDay = Format(Day(EndDate), "00")
    EndYear = Format(Year(EndDate), "00")
    qurl = "URL;http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + stockTicker + "&f=nxj1b4abc1p2"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=qurl, Destination:=Range(DestinationCell))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        '    .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        '    .RefreshPeriod = 0
        '    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        '    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        '    .WebTables = "20"
        '    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        '    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        '    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        '    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        '    .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
ErrorHandler:

End Sub

Sub DownloadData()

    Dim frequency As String
    Dim numRows As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim lastErrorRow As Integer
    Dim lastSuccessRow As Integer
    Dim stockTicker As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastRow = Worksheets("Kursabruf").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through all tickers
    For ticker = 2 To lastRow

        stockTicker = Worksheets("Kursabruf").Range("$a$" & ticker)

        If stockTicker = "" Then
            GoTo NextIteration
        End If

        Call DownloadStockQuotes(stockTicker, "$c$2")
        Worksheets("Kursabruf").Columns("c:c").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("c2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                     TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                                     DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=" ", _
                                     Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1))

        Sheets(stockTicker).Columns("A:G").ColumnWidth = 10

        lastRow = Sheets(stockTicker).UsedRange.Row - 2 + Sheets(stockTicker).UsedRange.Rows.Count

            GoTo NextIteration

        'Delete final blank row otherwise will get ,,,, at bottom of CSV
        Sheets("Kursabruf").Rows(lastRow + 1 & ":" & Sheets("Kursabruf").Rows.Count).Delete


NextIteration:
    Next ticker

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


ErrorHandler:

    Worksheets("Parameters").Select
    For Each C In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        C.Delete
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If you can detail the errors you are getting, we will help you debug the code

Comment: Doesn't yahoo lets you download data to excel or did they remove that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your offer to help! Right now it's saying destination reference is not valid in the field 'Worksheets("Kursabruf").Columns("c:c").TextToColumns ...' - right after the Call of the stock download function. Regarding your question, @findwindow: Do you mean download in another way than via VBA? Please explain! :) Thanks again!

Comment: It's been years but last time I used it, yahoo has a link to download data direct to excel. Guessing it's not there anymore? Have you tried google finance or morningstar? Edit: also, most people don't pull stock data. If you are, you should have access to bloomberg or similar.

Comment: Ah! MSN service is available, but I like the flexibility of the Yahoo API. I can chose from dozens of different values and customize my request. The one thing I can't seem to get done myself is how I get the result of my request URL into my excel file. CSV export is easy (explained in that first link I posted).

Comment: Too lazy to read the links XD Try adding the worksheet before `Range("c2")`

Comment: Doesn't change the problem, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Too lazy to read the documentation XD Doesn't seem to matter if the ranges are equal... Edit: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431231/convert-text-to-columns-in-excel-using-vba) help?