# Filter unformatted e-mail information

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I get unformatted Outlook e-mail:
[image]

I created VBA code to receive these e-mails and add the body to a .xlsx file.

Now I need to put that data into cells. Currently it is added to a single cell.

Is there a way to filter that data to, for example, insert the value 202117 into a cell in a spreadsheet?

```vb
Public WithEvents GMailItems As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set GMailItems = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub GMailItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim xMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xExcelFile As String
    Dim xExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xWs As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xNextEmptyRow As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    If Item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub
    Set xMailItem = Item
    xExcelFile = "FILE LOCATION"
    If IsWorkBookOpen(xExcelFile) = True Then
        Set xExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        Set xWb = GetObject(xExcelFile)
        If Not xWb Is Nothing Then xWb.Close True
    Else
        Set xExcelApp = New Excel.Application
    End If
    Set xWb = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(xExcelFile)
    Set xWs = xWb.Sheets(1)
    xNextEmptyRow = xWs.Range("B" & xWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With xWs
        .Cells(xNextEmptyRow, 1) = xNextEmptyRow - 1
        .Cells(xNextEmptyRow, 2) = xMailItem.Body
        .Cells(xNextEmptyRow, 3) = xMailItem.SenderName
        .Cells(xNextEmptyRow, 4) = xMailItem.Subject
        .Cells(xNextEmptyRow, 5) = xMailItem.ReceivedTime
    End With
    xWs.Columns("A:E").AutoFit
    xWb.Save
End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim xFreeFile As Long, xErrNo As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    xFreeFile = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #xFreeFile
    Close xFreeFile
    xErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0
    Select Case xErrNo
        Case 0: IsWorkBookOpen = False
        Case 70: IsWorkBookOpen = True
        Case Else: Error xErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: If you have existing code it's always useful to include it in your post.

Comment: @TimWilliams updated! thanks.

Comment: For anyone reading this: look that all e-mail body is being exported to a single cell:         .Cells(xNextEmptyRow, 2) = xMailItem.Body

Comment: That looks like a "fixed width" output, so you should be able to (a) split on vbCR or vbCrLf to get an array of lines from  `xMailItem.Body` (b) Use `Mid(startPos, length)` on each line to extract the item(s) of interest.

Comment: I would look at using the functionality "Text to Columns" (under the Data menu in Excel). Record a macro to get the settings if you can make it work and it should come out something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431231/convert-text-to-columns-in-excel-using-vba

Comment: @Tragamor that was exactly the solution I've found. Thanks - it works like a charm.